# c++ should i bother deleting pointers to application lifetime variables?

Tags: c++, memory

I have a few "global" constructs that are allocated with new and are alive the entirety of the applications life span.

Should i bother calling delete on the pointers just before the application finishes? 
Doesn't all the of the applications memory get reclaimed after it closes anyway?

Edit For Clarity. I am only talking about not calling delete for lifetime objects who "die" right as the program is closing.

Comment: Why not change your global variable from a pointer to a smart pointer? You *might* still run into order of destruction issues, but only rarely. It depends a bit on how you set things up in the first place -- if the (smart) pointer begins as null and is later assigned to, then it's usually harder to keep track of the correct con/destruction order than if the (smart) pointer is initialized with the allocated object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't write/debug/maintain code to do something that the OS is already very good at.

Unless there are specific reasons to the contrary, (eg. outstanding transactions to be commited, files to flush, connections to be closed), I don't bother writing code to do something that the OS is going to do anyway. If a dtor does nothing special, why bother calling it?

Many developers put in a lot of effort into deleting/destroying/freeing/terminating stuff at app close time - a load of effort to avoid some spurious 'leak report' on app shutdown from a memory manager that is itself about to be destroyed.

Comment: This is incredible. How did the answer with 0 upvotes get selected over the [correct] one with 9 upvotes? The problem, Martin, with your approach is that it requires too much knowledge. That is, you have to *know for each individual case* whether the destructor "does something special". It's much better to get into the habit of always writing the code correctly, then it doesn't matter how the destructor is written. That's *especially* true if you're calling library code where you have no way of even knowing what the destructor does.

Comment: The general lesson is that it's not about making code easy to *write*, it's about making it easy to *maintain*!

Comment: If you don't tidy up to remove "spurious" leak reports, how are you going to figure out which leak reports aren't "spurious"?

Comment: @CodyGray - maybe because the answer with 9, (11 now), upvotes is not contrary to my answer, but complements it.

Comment: @CodyGray - I agree with the maintenance issue - I have done a lot of code maintenance on other developers' code :(  A shutdown sequence for a complex app is non-trivial.  It requires design, implementation, testing and maintenance. If it can be minimized, or even avoided completely, the app will be more reliable and require less maintenance.

Comment: Looks contrary to me. You're implying a very different style of programming than sharptooth describes. I call yours either "lazy" or "sloppy", but those are pretty loaded and pejorative terms. Probably neither is fair; I understand your point. But I think it's a bad style in general for the reasons I already described. I don't really see how the two answers are complimentary beyond the fact that they both respond to the same question. Yes, shutdown sequences can fail, but when they do, the OS will take care of reclaiming memory just as if your app crashed by any other means.

Comment: @CodyGray - one way is pseudo-statistical.  If the leak report is always there, always the same size, always the same number and never changes up or down during testing, it can be classed as spurious and unimportant.  If it grows or multiplies, you have a problem!

Comment: @CodyGray - 'shutdown sequences can fail, but when they do, the OS will take care of reclaiming memory just as if your app crashed by any other means' - that's the best scenario.  The more usual one is a support call: 'Hey - I've got all these zombie processes', 'Hey - the form has gone but the Task Manager shows 14 copies still running', 'Hey - your app is locked up and I can't get rid of the form except with the task manager', 'Hey - my screen is filling up with beeping 'Access Violation' boxes'.

Comment: Actually, OS is NOT 'very' good at this. Why would you ever rely or any automated process to do something for you ? In my humblemost opinion, this is just bad practice ...

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth well, I have no idea how to write code to remove all the threads of my app from the running state before releasing all handles amd memory.  The OS can do this just fine.  It does this 'automated process' for all my apps and I don't have to write/build/test/deliver/maintain any of it.  I use the OS for more things too - I don't, for example, attempt to read bytes from disk files by any other way than OS calls....

Comment: @MartinJames I have never said that you shouldn't utilize tools that OS can provide. I just reckon everyone should clear 'their own mess'. But then again, this is more of a question of 'style' than a question there's an objective answer for.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth - sure, I didn't particularly want to start a jihad over this 'cleanup' issue and I doubt that either CodyGray or myself are going to change their design strategy :)  'Cleaning up a mess'is sometimes very, very difficult without a big enough shovel.  24 threads in unknown states across six cores are very difficult to shut down cleanly if you don't have access to kernel structures and an inter-core driver.  My apps don't have this, the OS does.

Comment: @MartinJames I have never tried destroying 24 threads in unknown state so i have little to none experience with this particular matter and yes i can see how that could be fairly difficult if not impossible. But the question is of a different nature :) Tho i certainly don't want anyone to reconsider his design strategy just because of my comment, it's just my two cents :)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth - no it's not really.  If the threads are writing to buffers/whatever and the buffer instances are deleted while the threads are still running, a segfault/AV will be raised.  The shutdown/cleanup sequence then expands to 'ensure all the threads are not running and only then free the memory'. Developers then try to put explicit thread termination code into dtors.  Then, quite often, they post to stackoverflow with 'my app will not shut down' or 'how can I terminate my thread', (there are hundreds of these). Another approach is to just ask the OS to terminate the process..

Comment: +1 for this; I don't quite agree with Martin but I thinks his argument is valid and certainly doesn't deserve -2.

Comment: LOL, let's disable garbage collection in .NET then.

Comment: 'let's disable garbage collection in .NET then' - good idea, but I fear it may break existing code..  Merry Xmas everyone!

Answer (score 25):

Technically, yes, the memory is reclaimed. But unless you use `delete` the destructors  of those objects are not run and their side effect is not applied. This might lead to a temporary file not deleted or a database change not committed depending on what those destructor were meant to do.

Also don't forget Murphy. Now the code for managing those objects is used as you describe (objects have to persist for the life of the program) but later you might want to reuse the code so that it is run multiple times. Unless it can deal with recreating objects properly it will be leaking objects.

Comment: Murphy works both ways here.  If you don't delete, you can be sure that some of the objects have important behavior in their destructor.  If you do delete, you can be sure that the object is used in the destructor of some static object, and you'll run into order of destruction issues.

Comment: +1 for dtors.  There are, of course, cases where you definitely do not want the dtors called, eg. when they are stuck in a library and do silly things like waiting forever for a blocked thread to terminate.

Comment: It's also quite handy for memory tools, like valgrind, to give them a better change at finding what is actually a leak.

Comment: Probably, it is apt here to suggest/mention use of RAII and Smart pointers which will ensure automatic cleanup instead of remembering to call `delete` explicitly for each raw pointer.One more reason to avoid using raw pointers in C++.

Answer (score 2):

It is always good practice to clean up everything, although the memory is reclained these objects might have other resources allocated (shared memory, smeaphores etc) that should be cleaned up, probably by the objects destructors.

If you do not want to call delete use shared pointers to hold these resources, so that they are cleaned up correctly when the application exits.

How are you testing your application? Not cleaning up might hinder development of a decent test harness. Tests of the application might want a way of spoofing a shutdown and restart.

There is more to cleaning up that simple releasing memory.

Comment: Ther sure is, which is why it's best to avoid trying to do it yourself if there is a tried and tested alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably right, but I personally would consider it poor coding and bad practise to rely on the system and would ensure my code always tidied properly whe shutting down.

Comment: You do not trust your OS?  It's a waste to spend time on work that is already covered.  That, and the fact that apps which attempt to 'shut down cleanly' are often prone to not shutting down at all - they are actually less reliable than apps that just ask the OS to terminate them.

Comment: @Martin James:I take your point on repeating work, however I feel your argument is really an excuse for sloppy or shortcutting, habits of which will ultimately lead to problems.  No I absolutely do NOT trust an OS, you cannot assume that the OS will deal with everything correctly, there are so many permutations of OS /  updates etc on just about every platform, whether existing or future permutations that your code may come up against that you absolutely cannot assume everything will work as you intend it.  The only way to be absolutely sure is to ensure you deal with everything yourself.

Comment: my OS is soak-tested daily by billions of users.  I like to think that I write really good code, but I cannot afford the same amount of testing, so I try to leverage the OS as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer.  Most of the time, it probably doesn't
matter, but there are destructors which do something important, beyond
just freeing memory (I have one which deletes temporary files), which
argues in favor of cleanup; on the other hand, destructing such objects
may lead to order of destruction issues, if the objects are used by
destructors of other objects.  My general rule is to not destruct,
unless the destructor does something more than just free memory, but 
others may prefer a different set of defaults.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the destructors not being executed (as [sharptooth pointer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8588570/91757)), it's also worthwhile to delete global objects to make memory checkers happy. Especially if your code is in a shared library - you don't want to clutter their memory checker (say, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org)) output just because you didn't delete properly.

Comment: No.  Upside - no spurious leak log in valgrind.  Downside - coding, testing and maintenance of a shutdown mechanism.

Comment: @MartinJames: Chances are that coding, testing and maintenance are no downsides but simply required: imagine a shared library which `new`'s things globally but fails to `delete`. If this library gets loaded/unloaded repeatedly (using `dlopen`/`LoadLibrary` etc.), you'll actually keep leaking more and more resources. You *have to* handle this with code, testing and maintenance.

Comment: I posted 'no spurious leak'.  If a library leaks as you describe, then sure, fix the problem!  The only issue I have is with fixing problems that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

.. then there's those cases where you definitely don't want the dtor's called at all before the OS terminates the process, eg:

1) When the dtor does not work properly because it tries to terminate a thread, fails and blocks on the thread handle or other signal, (the perennial 'join/waitFor' deadlock) - the cause off 99% of all household 'my app will not close down cleanly' posts.

2) When the dtor does not work properly because it's just bad anyway and buried in a library.

3) Where the memory must outlive the process threads else there will be segfaults/AV on close, (eg. pools of buffer objects that threads may well be writing to at close time).

4) Any other 'special cases' where the destruction of the object/s has to be left to the OS.

There are so many 'special cases' that I regard 'cleaning up' shutdown code as the special case.